# Remove Duplicate Lines Starting With Certain String

Tags: python

How do I remove duplicate lines only if they start in a certain way?

Example input:

```
%start _CreditsInfo
-(half) userCoins {
return 1;
}
%start _CreditsInfo
-(half) userLives {
return 1;
}
```

Requested output:

```
%start _CreditsInfo
-(half) userCoins {
return 1;
}
-(half) userLives {
return 1;
}
```

As you can see, a normal duplicate removal won't work and I don't want to remove other duplicates than those starting with `%start`, such as `return x;`.

Comment: I've removed the backticks to change your code formatting from inline to block. Although Markdown uses a four-space indent, this is removed from the rendering of the block.

Comment: Readers are usually quite keen to see an initial attempt at a problem - did you try anything at all prior to posting this question?

Comment: @halfer Yeah I did, I learned from my mistake and included my attempts on my latest post. Also learned about the 4-space indent code block, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make each of the line starts (prefix) into a regular expression and keep a set of the ones you've already seen.

```
import re

class DuplicateFinder(object):

    def __init__(self, *prefixes):
        self.regexs = [re.compile('^{0}'.format(p)) for p in prefixes]
        self.duplicates = set()

    def not_duplicate(self, line):
        found = reduce(lambda r, p: r or p.search(line), self.regexs, False)
        if found:
            if found.re.pattern not in self.duplicates:
                self.duplicates.add(found.re.pattern)
                return True
            else:
                return False
        return True

df = DuplicateFinder('%start', '%other_start')


lines = """%start _CreditsInfo
-(half) userCoins {
return 1;
}
%start _CreditsInfo
-(half) userLives {
return 1;
}""".splitlines()

result = filter(df.not_duplicate, lines)

print '\n'.join(result)
```

Produces:

```
%start _CreditsInfo
-(half) userCoins {
return 1;
}
-(half) userLives {
return 1;
}
```